# How to setup ember engines?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js, ember-engines

I've created a standalone routable engine with `ember-engines` `0.4.0`, `ember-cli` `2.10.0`.

I get this error if I call the engines index route (`/thingy/`):

`Assertion Failed: Asset manifest does not list any available bundles.`

Consuming App `router.js`:

```js
this.mount('thingy-frontend', { as: 'thingy', path: 'thingy' });
```

Engine App `routes.js`:

```js
this.route('index', { path: '/' });
```

The engine is 'installed' via a symlink in the `node_modules/` dir of the consuming `ember-cli` app. ([See here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41165548/ember-engines-inside-rails-engines-via-ember-cli-rails/41180452#41180452)).

Just for fun I've tried to change the routes to test if that works ...

Consuming App `router.js`:

```js
this.mount('thingy-frontend', { as: 'thingy' });
```

Engine App `routes.js`:

```js
this.route('index', { path: 'new' });
```

I've called `/thingy/new` and got an `UnrecognizedURLError`. Alternative, if I call the root path, I get an `Assertion Failed: Asset manifest does not list any available bundles.`

Also if I place a `console.log('...');` in the engines `index.js`, I can't see any output. Seems like it isn't loaded at all.

The setup was inspired by the official README and the official example repos.

Any idea how to fix this Ember Engines setup?

You can find the repos on GitHub:

- Engine: https://github.com/phortx/ember-engines-engine
- Consuming App with README: https://github.com/phortx/ember-engines-app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We could solve the issue. There have been several problems and I'll share with you what we did:

## 1. Add ember-engines as dependency (not just dev-dependency)

You have to add`ember-engines` as a dependency in the `package.json` both for the app and the engine. So we change
the `package.json` to:

```json
"dependencies": {
  "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.10",
  "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7",
  "ember-data": "^2.10.0",
  "ember-engines": "0.4.0"
}
```

Don't forget to `npm install`.

## 2. Add the actual engine to the package.json

Even if it's not public and symlinked in node_modules like in our case, you have to add the engine to the `package.json`.

In our case this was `"thingy-frontend": "*"`.

Don't forget to `npm install`.

## 3. Check symlink name

In our case the symlink had the name of the engine repo instead of the actual engine name. That won't work. We changed
the symlink name to `thingy-frontend` (that's the name from the engines `index.js`).

## 4. Use the right resolver

You have to ensure, that both in the `addon/engine.js` and the `app/resolver.js` use the `ember-resolver`.

## 5. Failed to load asset manifest.

This is probably a bug in `ember-engines`. See the issue for more details: https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/issues/282#issuecomment-268834293

You can workaround that issue by manually adding a `<meta />`-Tag to the `<head>` (see the GitHub issue link above)

Many thanks to [Michael Donaldson](https://github.com/mike183)!

Comment: Thank you for this. but please remember when you say "package.json" the reader has NO IDEA to which package.json you are referring. There are TWO package.json files in an engines project (and possibly more), the "root" app's package.json and a package.json for EACH engine. Don't assume the reader somehow magically knows which file you're talking about.

Answer (score 4):

I can't find reference to your Engine app from Consuming app package.json. I think you should add to Consuming package.json Engine app. For in-repo-addons - engines I can find in ember-engines-demo that in package.json they have:

```
"ember-addon": {
    "paths": [
      "lib/ember-chat-engine"
    ]
 }
```

For not in-repo-addon, but for normal modules they have:

```
"dependencies": {
    "ember-data": "^2.6.0",
    "ember-engines": "dgeb/ember-engines#v0.2",
    "ember-blog-engine": "dgeb/ember-blog-engine"
  },
```

Notice ember-blog-engine. Here's full reference to their [package.json](https://github.com/dgeb/ember-engines-demo/blob/master/package.json).

However in your Consuming ember-engines-app app [package.json](https://github.com/phortx/ember-engines-app/blob/master/package.json) does not list 
ember-engines-engine name.

Ember processes addons from package.json lists so you have to reference your engine addon there. Otherwise you will never get any line of code from such package executed in Ember CLI environment.

Please add your ember-engines-engine to consuming app package.json.

Comment: Ran into this issue because I created an in-repo-addon by copying the files of an existing engine instead of using `ember generate in-repo-addon` :/

Answer (score 0):

I'd add that *incompatibility* could also be an issue...

As Ember Engines is experimental and being developed against the master branches of Ember and Ember-CLI, be sure that you are using **[compatible versions](https://github.com/ember-engines/ember-engines/blob/master/README.md#important-note-about-compatibility-and-stability)**.